# How to add ComponentScan.Filter in @EnableEntityDefinedRegion

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

When I added an `includeFilter` to `@EnableEntityDefinedRegion`, it still scanned the whole entity package and created all Region beans. How do I scan the specific Region class? For example, only "Address" Region.

```
package org.test.entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Region("Address")
public class GfAddress implements Serializable

package org.test.entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Region("CreditCard")
public class GfCreditCard implements Serializable

package org.test.package
public interface IAddressRepository extends GemfireRepository<GfAddress, String>

package org.test.package
public interface ICreditCardRepository extends GemfireRepository<GfCreditCard , String>

@Service
@ClientCacheApplication
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackages = IAddressRepository.class, includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes=AddressRepository.class))
@EnableEntityDefinedRegion(basePackages = GfAddress.class, includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="GfAddress*"))
public class AddressDataAccess
```

When I print all the beans that are loaded, I found out that the following beans are created.

1. Address
2. CreditCard
3. IAddressRepository
4. AddressDataAccess

Version

1. GemFire : 9.8.6
2. spring-data-gemfire : 2.1.0
3. Spring Boot : 2.1.0

Comment: Hi Jack- Just wanted to give you a heads up that I am currently investigating this.  I think I found the issue and I am currently writing a few tests to verify.  Effectively, SDG also provides include filters, by default, which are overriding the user-defined include filters.  If I am correct, this is a rather simple fix.  I will follow up with a complete answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay.

First, have a look at the SDG JIRA ticket I filed, [DATAGEODE-352 - "EnableEntityDefinedRegions.includeFilters are inappropriately overridden by framework provided include filters"](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-352).

In this ticket, I describe a couple of workarounds to this bug (!) in the comments, starting [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-352?focusedCommentId=189411&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-189411).

I'd also be careful about your REGEX.  I am no *Regular Expression* expert, but I am certain "`GfAddress*`" will not properly match the application entity type you are searching for and trying to match even when you pick up the new SDG bits resolving the issue I filed.

I created a similar test, using REGEX, to verify the resolution of the issue, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/master/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableEntityDefinedRegionsWithRegexFilterIntegrationTests.java).  This is the [REGEX I specified](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/master/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableEntityDefinedRegionsWithRegexFilterIntegrationTests.java#L113).  Using "`Programmer*`" did not work, as I suspected!  That is because the REGEX is not valid and does not match the FQCN as used in the Spring `RegexPatternTypeFilter`.

Technically, it would be better to be a bit more specific about your type matching and use a "ASSIGNABLE_TYPE" `TypeFilter` instead, as this [test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/master/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableEntityDefinedRegionsWithAssignableTypeFilterIntegrationTests.java) demonstrates.

Finally, while SDG `2.1.x` is compatible with GemFire `9.8.x`, SD[G] `Lovelace`, or `2.1.x` (e.g. `2.1.18.RELEASE`), is officially based on, and only "supports", VMware GemFire `9.5.x` ([currently `9.5.4`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.1.18.RELEASE/pom.xml#L25)).

SDG `2.2.x` is officially based on, and "supports", VMware GemFire 9.8.x ([currently at 9.8.8](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.2.x/pom.xml#L25)).

You can review the **new** SDG [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Apache-Geode-&--Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-and-Support-Matrix#sdg-compatibility-matrix) for more details.

If you have more questions, please follow up here or in [DATAGEODE-352](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-352).